# How to resolve gem5 Error during SCons build

Tags: scons, gem5

I'm using gem5 simulator and also additionally some sys-object add my gem5 folder.

After to build some Error occurs.

So please kindly solve resolve my issue ,

Error Screen shot attachment Here kindly review that.

[image: Error Screen Shot]

Comment: You're at the least missing development packages for libpng.  Nobody who doesn't know this piece of software is likely to know where the `SimObject` functionality comes from, the quess would be it's some tool that has to be added to the scons environment - that's not a function that's defined in scons itself.  Probably there's something about that in the requirements-to-build?

Comment: Please paste text instead of screenshot. It's much easier to read.  Here's a link to report problems to the Gem5 project. https://www.gem5.org/documentation/reporting_problems/

Comment: Give us your exact gem5 version, distro version and GCC version, and highly recommend also sending build problems to mailing list or bug tracker: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5

Comment: Hi! currently, I'm facing the same problem, did you find any answer for it?

Answer (score 1):

The extended build guide is a bit hidden on the gem5 page. [You can find it here.](https://www.gem5.org/documentation/general_docs/building)

It suggests running

```
sudo apt install build-essential git m4 scons zlib1g zlib1g-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libprotoc-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev python-dev python libboost-all-dev
```

before trying to compile. This solves most of the problems.
Additionally, the installation of

```
 sudo apt install python-six zlib1g-dev libpng-dev swig
```

solved some problems for me.